# React-Native unable to load my tensorflow model .bin (weights) files

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

I was trying to load my model from python that i already converted to .bin and .json files, i also concated the bin files to one single bin file and when loading those model it give an error saying that those file did not exist and i already make sure that it was in the right folder and with the correct casing i even copy-pasted those files in some of the folders but to no avail.

It give me this error

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./assets/model/shard.bin from /home/lydianjay/Documents/ReactNative/Pothole/App.tsx: 

None of these files exist:
  * assets/model/shard.bin(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * assets/model/shard.bin/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  18 |     await tf.ready();
  19 |     const modelJson = require('./assets/model/model.json');
> 20 |     const modelWeights = require('./assets/model/shard.bin');
```

and this is my code

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import { fetch } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = useState(null);
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadModel();
  }, []);

  const loadModel = async () => {
    console.log(__dirname);
    await tf.ready();
    const modelJson = require('./assets/model/model.json');
    const modelWeights = require('./assets/model/shard.bin');
    const loadedModel = await tf.loadGraphModel(tf.io.bundleResource(modelJson, modelWeights));
    setModel(loadedModel);
    console.log('Model Loaded!');
  };

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
      setCapturedImage(data.uri);
      console.log('Captured!');
      // Use the loaded model for inference or further processing
      if (model) {
        // Example: Perform inference on the captured image
        const imageTensor = preprocessImage(data.uri);
        const prediction = await model.predict(imageTensor);
        // Process the prediction result as needed
        console.log('Prediction:', prediction);
      }
    }
  };

  const preprocessImage = async (uri) => {
    // Load the image using React Native's Image component
    const image = await Image.prefetch(uri);

    // Create a canvas element with the desired size
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;

    // Draw the image onto the canvas with the desired size
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200);

    // Convert the canvas to a TensorFlow.js tensor
    const imageTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas).toFloat();

    // Normalize the pixel values if needed
    // Example: Divide by 255 to scale the pixel values to [0, 1]
    const normalizedImage = imageTensor.div(255);

    // Expand dimensions to match the model's input shape if needed
    // Example: Add an extra dimension at axis 0 to create a batch of 1 image
    const expandedImage = normalizedImage.expandDims(0);

    return expandedImage;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.defaultStyle}>
      <RNCamera
        style={styles.camera}
        ref={cameraRef}
        type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
        captureAudio={false}
      >
        {capturedImage && (
          <Image source={{ uri: capturedImage }} style={styles.previewImage} />
        )}
      </RNCamera>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={takePicture}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Capture</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  defaultStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  previewImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '80%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
   position: 'absolute',
    top: '90%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '40%',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    padding: 12,
    borderRadius: 24,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'black',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  camera: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

export default App;
```

my metro.config.js

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['bin', 'txt', 'jpg', 'ttf', 'png'],
    sourceExts: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'jsx'],
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/platform_node/])
  },
};
```

I already double check the files and i even copy my files in different folders

I also change my build.gradle as chat gpt suggested

```
project.ext.react = [ extraPackagerArgs: ["--assetExts", "bin, json", "bin"] ]
```